# Hibernate search custom stop words list

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I need to customize stopwords list for search by `Document` title.
I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(
        name = "documentAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(
                        factory = StopFilterFactory.class,
                        params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "stoplist.properties"),
                                @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true")
                        }
                )
        }
)
public class Document {

    ...

    @Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "documentAnalyzer"))
    private String title;

    ...
}
```

`stoplist.properties` file is in `resources` directory and contains stopwords that are different from `StandardAnalyzer` defaults.

But the search doesn't return any results if I use stopwords that are enabled by default but don't exist in my `stoplist.properties` file, e.g. the word `will`.

What is wrong with current configuration?
How can I make hibernate search use custom stopwords list?

I use hibernate-search-orm 5.6.1 version.

Results are validated in an integration test with index created on-the-fly:

```
@Before
public void setUpLuceneIndex() throws InterruptedException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks sane as far as I can see.

Did you reindex your entities after having changed the stop words configuration? You need that for the new configuration to be taken into account at index time.

If you did and it still does not work, try to add a breakpoint in StopFilterFactory constructor and inform method to see what's going on!

Comment: Entities are getting indexed in an integration test (updated question description with additional information) that I use to verify search. I've looked into `StopFilterFactory`, `stopWords` property is populated with words from my custom property file. This solution doesn't work still.

Comment: Weird. Try to reproduce it with our test case template: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene . It might help you find the issue and if not I'll take a look!

Comment: I've just added custom analyzer to all indexed fields and the whole solution started working fine. Thanks for test case template.