# Search for "this" or "not" with Hibernate Search / Lucene

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to search for words "this" and "not" with Hibernate Search using Lucene as a search engine?
Today I added in my web catalog of products a product called [Shhh This Is Not Milk](https://thevegcat.com/en-us/articles/alpro/shhh-this-is-not-milk-plant-based-whole-3-5-fat). The only two words that Lucene accepts are "Shhh" and "Milk" and other 3 words are ignored. If I put "Shhh" as a search word, it can be found and also if I put "Alpro Milk" as a search words, it can be found (one of many). But if I put "This" or "Not" or "This Is" or "This Is Not" or "This Not" or "Not Milk" - I'm getting no results.
I am aware those are special words but how to avoid this behaviour?

While building a search query I use `AND` operator between search words.

Hibernate is version 5, Spring Boot is version 2.7.7, Java is 18, the database is MySQL.

Comment: You can define a custom stop-word list for your Lucene analyzer - for example,  Lucene's [standard English stop-word list](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/d5d6dc079395c47cd6d12dcce3bcfdd2c7d9dc63/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.java#L43), but with these specific words removed (so they will get indexed). Example: [Hibernate search custom stop words list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47111852/12567365)

Comment: Found this one before posting my question but from comments I could guess it's not working. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: One comment says "_the whole solution started working fine_"... Also, make sure you use the same analyzer (and same custom stop-word list) for searching that you use for indexing. If it does not work for you, you can post what you have as a [mre] and I'm sure someone will help.